# using dictionaries/classes in python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary, store

Hi im trying to create a program where a user input would be stored in a dictionary/class (really new to this unsure of the terminology).

but basically i would like to have 3 dictionaries/classes at the begining of my code which will store the information of three teams e.g. team name, then how many points the have gained over the past 3 weeks.

the user will then enter the next weeks points to be stored into the class/dictionary which will in turn removed the previous 3rd week.

```
Premiership = {
    "Arsenal": ['points': 23,20,19],
    "Chelsea": ['points': 15,14,11],
    "Man utd": ['points' : 20, 17, 14],
}

Championship = {
    "Derby county": ['points': 23,20,19],
    "QPR": ['points': 15,14,11],
    "Leeds Utd": ['points' : 20, 17, 14],
}

League one = {
    "Sheffield utd": ['points': 23,20,19],
    "Barnsley": ['points': 15,14,11],
    "Bradford city": ['points' : 20, 17, 14],
}
```

so they would select the league by:

```
selection = raw_input('please choose a league: ')
```

then once they have done that i want to allow the user to update the score and get rid of one

Comment: Not sure what is the actual problem.. Anyway, looks like you should take a look at the [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off on how the dictionaries are built.  You Sub contain an invalid syntax list and should look closer to:

```
Premiership = {
    "Arsenal": {'points': [23,20,19]},
    "Chelsea": {'points': [15,14,11]},
    "Man utd": {'points' : [20, 17, 14]},
}
```

A better way may be to change your formatting a slight bit, as with the current scenario the "points" field isn't providing any benifit

```
Premiership = {
    "Arsenal": [23,20,19],
    "Chelsea": [15,14,11],
    "Man utd": [20, 17, 14],
}
```

You can than access the content in the Premiership dictionary as follows

```
Premiership["Arsenal"][0] = <<new value>>
```

You will than need to figure out your logic in how you rotate your list values